# Convert each element in col of df from string to a list

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

Input :

If this was one of the values in the col of a df

'dog went to the kennel and drank his water'

Output:
I want this as the converted value ( str to list )
['dog went to the kennel and drank his water']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [str(x)])
```

I applied it to the following data to show the conversion:

```
df                                                                                                                                                                                               
#    col1                              col2
# 0  Bill  954E47384F568F91851E1BABE25850XX
# 1  Will  954E47584F568F91851E1BABE25850XX

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [str(x)])  

df
#     col1                              col2
# 0  [Bill]  954E47384F568F91851E1BABE25850XX
# 1  [Will]  954E47584F568F91851E1BABE25850XX

df.col1[0] 
# ['Bill']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple!

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

Hope it helps!